# How to install node js App in CPanel/Shared Hosting

Tags: node.js, cpanel, shared-hosting

I wanted to host my Node js application using CPanel with shared hosting.
Can you please help me with it.

Comment: Read the documentation https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few steps to host your Node.js App using Cpanel.

1. Login to your CPanel Account
2. Go to Software Tab and Select "SetUp Node.js App"
   [image: Select Setup Node.js App]
3. Click Create Application Button
   [image]
4. Fill Application root, Application URL and Application Startup File and Click Create Button
   [image]
5. Go to file Manager and Create package.json file in the app file directory. and add this

   {
   "name": "Node App",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC"
   }
6. Go to Setup Node.js App and select Edit icon to run npm install
   [image]
   [image]
   it may take time to show Run Npm button
7. You are all done and run your Node.js app

Comment: I hope it may help.

Comment: I do not have this node js option under softwares what should i do?

Comment: @AhmadMalik Maybe your hosting server is not supporting this.